# Non divisible subset-Hackerrank solution in C

Tags: c, algorithm

I am new to programming and C is the only language I know. Read a few answers for the same question written in other programming languages. I have written some code for the same but I only get a few test cases correct (4 to be precise). How do I edit my code to get accepted?

I have tried comparing one element of the array with the rest and then I remove the element (which is being compared with the initial) if their sum is divisible by k and then this continues until there are two elements in the array where their sum is divisible by k. Here is the link to the question:
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/non-divisible-subset/problem

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void remove_element(int array[],int position,long int *n){
    int i;
    for(i=position;i<=(*n)-1;i++){
        array[i]=array[i+1];
    }
    *n=*n-1;
}
int main(){
    int k;
    long int n;
    scanf("%ld",&n);
    scanf("%d",&k);
    int *array=malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        scanf("%d",&array[i]);
    for(i=n-1;i>=0;i--){
        int counter=0;
        for(j=n-1;j>=0;j--){
            if((i!=j)&&(array[i]+array[j])%k==0)
            {
                remove_element(array,j,&n);
                j--;
                continue;
            }
            else if((i!=j)&&(array[i]+array[j])%k!=0){
                counter++;
        }
        }

        if(counter==n-1){
            printf("%ld",n);
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I only get about 4 test cases right from 20 test cases.

Answer (score 0):

What Gerhardh in his comment hinted at is that

```
    for(i=position;i<=(*n)-1;i++){
        array[i]=array[i+1];
    }
```

reads from `array[*n]` when `i` = `*n-1`, overrunning the array. Change that to

```
    for (i=position; i<*n-1; i++)
        array[i]=array[i+1];
```

Additionally, you have

```
                remove_element(array,j,&n);
                j--;
```

- but `j` will be decremented when continuing the `for` loop, so decrementing it here is one time too many, while adjustment of `i` is necessary, since `remove_element()` shifted `array[i]` one position to the left, so change `j--` to `i--`.

Furthermore, the condition

```
        if(counter==n-1){
            printf("%ld",n);
            break;
        }
```

makes just no sense; remove that block and place `printf("%ld\n", n);` before the `return 0;`.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this efficiently, you have to realize several things:

1. Two positive integer numbers `a` and `b` are divisible by `k` (also positive integer number) if `((a%k) + (b%k))%k = 0`. That means, that either `((a%k) + (b%k)) = 0` (1) or `((a%k) + (b%k)) = k` (2).
2. Case (1) `((a%k) + (b%k)) = 0` is possible only if both `a` and `b` are multiples of `k` or `a%k=0 and b%k=0`. For case (2) , there are at most `k/2` possible pairs. So, our task is to pick elements that don't fall in case 1 or 2.
3. To do this, map each number in your array to its corresponding remainder by modulo `k`. For this, create a new array `remainders` in which an index stands for a remainder, and a value stands for numbers having such remainder.
4. Go over the new array `remainders` and handle 3 cases.

   4.1 If `remainders[0] > 0`, then we can still pick only one element from the original (if we pick more, then sum of their remainders `0`, so they are divisible by `k`!!!).

   4.2 if `k` is even and `remainders[k/2] > 0`, then we can also pick only one element (otherwise their sum is `k`!!!).

   4.3 What about the other numbers? Well, for any remainder `rem > 0` make sure to pick `max(remainders[rem], remainders[k - rem])`. You can't pick both since `rem + k - rem = k`, so numbers from such groups can be divisible by `k`.

Now, the code:

```
int nonDivisibleSubset(int k, int s_count, int* s) {
    static int remainders[101];
    for (int i = 0; i < s_count; i++) {
        int rem = s[i] % k;
        remainders[rem]++;
    }
    
    int maxSize = 0;
    bool isKOdd = k & 1; 
    int halfK  = k / 2;
    for (int rem = 0; rem <= halfK; rem++) {
        if (rem == 0) {
            maxSize += remainders[rem] > 0;  
            continue;      
        }
        
        if (!isKOdd && (rem == halfK)) {
            maxSize++;
            continue;
        } 

        int otherRem = k - rem;
        if (remainders[rem] > remainders[otherRem]) {
            maxSize += remainders[rem];
        } else {
            maxSize += remainders[otherRem];
        }
    }
    
    return maxSize;
}
```